# Safari extension have different session that web application

Tags: php, codeigniter, safari-extension

I have an issue with sessions in safari extension. The web application session and safari extension don't synchronize. I have two different sessions for extension and the web application. So when I'm logging in from the extension the web application is not logged in, when I'm logging in from web application the extension is not logged in correctly. I'm using code igniter for the web application. For sessions/cookies in extension I have a controller that is implemented as an api. For Firefox and Chrome everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. The solution was to create a login session from injected code in page.